# Apache Thrift Compilation C++

Tags: java, c++, thrift

I am facing an issue with the Apache Thrift client using C++, the server is created in Java.
I have downloaded the [latest thrift application](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/thrift/0.9.1/thrift-0.9.1.exe). I have created the thrift server using Java. 
Based on the [thrift tutorial](http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/), I have generated the CPP files.

In order to compile the files, lot of header files are required. When I checked the [compilation requirements](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/), there are nearly 12 tools are required as a pre-requisite and each of them having their own dependency.

Is there any bundled package for compiling the generated CPP files or any idea about proceeding further? Any help regarding the same will be appreciated.

Comment: You're not very clear about what your problem is? You need to have the tools installed in order to build the package. Most linux distributions will have these available as packages.

Comment: @mikea, Am building it on windows machine. I would like to know any bundles available for the same, it is very difficult to download all the tools, setting their setups. Any single archives would be helpful.

Comment: Are you wanting to use the C++ client on vanilla windows? If so, I think you are out of luck. I don't think it's supported out of the box. Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249985/making-thrift-calls-from-a-c-app-in-windows. It's quite old but might still be relevant.

Comment: The C++ support has improved lately, and there's even an VS project. Don't confuse the requirements to build the **Thrift compiler** with the requirements to build the **Thrift Library**. You don't have to build the compiler on your own. The stable 0.9.1 version Windows compiler is available on the http://thrift.apache.org download page as a prebuilt EXE. The libs need only boost, libevent and zlib (if the list is correct).

Comment: @JensG I don't think those three software are only required, because I can't compile with those. I checked [another post](http://peoplesnote.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) mentioned by mikea I got what I want.

Comment: @mikea Thanks for taking me there, I was searching for something like [Peoplesnote](http://peoplesnote.codeplex.com) only.